# Angular: How do I define a default value when I close the Mat Dialog by clicking outside of the dialog

Tags: angular

I want to emit a default value, when the dialog is closed by clicking outside of the dialog. Currently it emits `undefined` which is okay for many situations, but **I want to emit a default value when the dialog was aborted by clicking outside.**

**How do I achieve this behavior?**

Here is an actual example:
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

1. Open the dialog.
2. Type somthing in the dialog.
3. Open it again.
4. Click outside of it and look at the disappearing value

**How do I want it to behave?**

It should always show up some values when the dialog was closed by clicking outside.

Answer (score 6):

> Use backdropClick observable that emits when the overlay's backdrop has been clicked

Then use MatDialogRef instace to accesss close method which accepts optional argument. Use that to provide value

**Try this**

component.ts

```
dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(v=>{
      dialogRef.close('Hello!');
 });

 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  this.animal = result;
 });
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9njqo)

Answer (score 0):

based on the example, you can add an OR operator :

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result || defaultValue;
    });
```

Comment: It is possible to define it inside the dialog? Like to have directly the default value emitted instead of doing it inside the subscription

Comment: i don't think so as the only way to pass data is to call the `close()` function of `dialogRef`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  this.animal = result;
});
```

In this code the result is automatically overwritten with undefined.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  if(!!result){
      this.animal = result;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution who working great in Angular 9 ->

```
addNew() {
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
```

}

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is not required to disable the close.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the dialogRef in the constructor of the DialogComponent,

```
constructor(
  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>
){}
```

And then within your dialog you can set up the subscription to backdropClick

```
this.dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(()=>{
      this.dialogRef.close(this.result || this.defaultValue);
 });
```

With that you should now be able to subscribe to afterClosed from outside the dialog as normal